# How to Connect webApp to Android app and Setting up URI Path?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-developer-api

As I am developing an app that downloads mp3, need to connect it with the web app, so that it takes URI from the webapp and to be set in our android app, so that a song can be downloaded. 
How Connection is made and how to set the URI?
please help me regarding this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial website. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `WebView`.

> If you want to deliver a web application (or just a web page) as a part of a client application, you can do it using WebView.

Just go to [Android Developers Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and get started! ;)